# Why does fstream not write to the file?

Tags: c++, xcode, visual-c++

My Code:

```
ifstream studentList;
studentList.open("ListOfStudents.txt");
studentList << firstName << endl;
studentList.close();
```

Whenever I run my program it says "no match for 'operator<<' ". I have been trying to solve this issue but nothing is working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have `#include <fstream>` and `#include <string>` in your code?

Comment: [`ifstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) opens the file for reading only. Use `ofstream` or `fstream`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::ifstream` is for INPUT ONLY (the `std::ios::in` flag is set), so you can't write to it.

You need to use `std::ofstream` instead (OUTPUT ONLY), or `std::fstream` with the `std::ios::out` flag explicitly set.

```cpp
ofstream studentList;
studentList.open("ListOfStudents.txt");
studentList << firstName << endl;
studentList.close();
```

```cpp
fstream studentList;
studentList.open("ListOfStudents.txt", ios::out);
studentList << firstName << endl;
studentList.close();
```

Comment: Thanks alot,I had been trying to debug this for like an hour because i used the same syntax in a different function and it was working all right.